# Pandas dataframe merge statement question

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm quite new to using Pandas. I was tasked with making some changes to an existing script with zero documentation.

I'm having a hard time deciphering what is happening in the second line:

```
lookuptable = pd.read_csv('Lookuptable_clusters_external_CO.csv')
...
...
products[['height', 'width', 'depth']] = products.merge(lookuptable, on=['unit', 'category', 'size'], how='left')[['height', 'width', 'depth']].astype(int)
```

products is a pandas dataframe filled with some info form a CSV file.
I understand that merge is used as kind of a SQL Join, but from what I've investigated, the structure of the merge statement (and the whole line actually) seems strange. I understand the on and how parameters, but I'm not sure what lookuptable is merging with, and what "[['height', 'width', 'depth']].astype(int)" does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this isn't a merge in the true sense, you're doing a merge to grab values, but then re-assigning them based on the index location, which will fail if you ever have duplicate keys and return a larger index, you need to re-assign the entire dataframe.

In regards to your question.

you are joining on these three fields.

`['unit', 'category', 'size']`

`[['height', 'width', 'depth']].astype(int)`

selects only those columns from your join clause, to re-assign them.

`.astype(int)` forces the values into integers.

I would re-write this as follows.

```
target_cols = ['height', 'width', 'depth']
merge_cols = ['unit', 'category', 'size']

lookuptable[trg_cols] = lookuptable[trg_cols].astype(int)

products = pd.merge(
              products,
              lookuptable[target_cols + merge_cols],
            on = merge_cols,
            how = 'left')
```

Comment: You've conflated the merge keys with the columns the OP wants from the merged tables

Comment: Thanks! It's way clearer now... Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The last two bits are selecting the final columns of the merged dataframe and converting every column to integers.

This is called method chaining. I would have written it like this:

```py
products.loc[:, ['height', 'width', 'depth']] = (
    products.merge(lookuptable, on=['unit', 'category', 'size'], how='left')
    .loc[:, ['height', 'width', 'depth']]
    .astype(int)
)
```

Here, every line returns acts on and returns a dataframe.

And I agree with the commenter that that assigning a selection based on a selection of a merge is strange. I would do:

```py
lookuptable = pd.read_csv(
    'Lookuptable_clusters_external_CO.csv',
    usecols=['unit', 'category', 'size', 'height', 'width', 'depth']
)

products = (
    products
    .merge(lookuptable, on=['unit', 'category', 'size'], how='left')
    .astype(int)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Follow @Manakin's solution to use the merge to add the columns to the DataFrame itself.

Your current statement assigns the results of a merge back to the DataFrame itself, which is highly problematic because:

1. Even a `'left'` merge can change the shape of the DataFrame if there are duplicate keys in the right DataFrame.
2. Merges can **destroy** the DataFrame index, meaning that your assignment back will not align as you expect.

The second part is a bit more nuanced, but is a real possibility because newer versions of `pandas` allow things in the Index to be used as merge keys.

Here's a simle example:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'foo': range(5)}, index=pd.Index(list('abcde'), name='key'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['e', 'a'], 'val': [11, 22]}, index=['foo', 'bar'])
```

Merging these two DataFrames there are some matches, but `pandas` reconstructed a brand new RangeIndex for the merge result.

```
df1.merge(df2, on='key', how='left')
#  key  foo   val
#0   a    0  22.0
#1   b    1   NaN
#2   c    2   NaN
#3   d    3   NaN
#4   e    4  11.0
```

And so despite what should have merged, index mis-alignment means nothing gets brought back to the DataFrame with the assignment:

```
df1['val'] = df1.merge(df2, on='key', how='left')[['val']]
#     foo  val
#key          
#a      0  NaN
#b      1  NaN
#c      2  NaN
#d      3  NaN
#e      4  NaN
```